# Converting parent & child dictionary list to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, nested, hierarchy

I tried and saw multiple solutions for the above question but could not find a solution that suits my case. I have following list of dictionaries.

```
[
        {"id": "101", "logical_section": "ORGANIZATION", "parent_section_id": None},
        {"id": "102", "logical_section": "ORG_NAMES", "parent_section_id": "101"},
        {"id": "103", "logical_section": "ORG_ADDRESSES", "parent_section_id": "101"},
        {"id": "104", "logical_section": "SOURCEADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"},
        {"id": "105", "logical_section": "STANDARDIZEDADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"},
        {"id": "106", "logical_section": "ORG_EMPLOYES", "parent_section_id": "101"}
]
```

and I need to convert this list to list of nested dictionaries in the following way

```
{
    "id": "101",
    "logical_section": "ORGANIZATION",
    "parent_section_id": None,
    "child": [
        {
            "id": "102",
            "logical_section": "ORG_NAMES",
            "parent_section_id": "101"
        },
        {
            "id": "103",
            "logical_section": "ORG_ADDRESSES",
            "parent_section_id": "101",
            "child": [
                {"id": "104", "logical_section": "SOURCEADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"},
                {"id": "105", "logical_section": "STANDARDIZEDADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "106",
            "logical_section": "ORG_EMPLOYES",
            "parent_section_id": "101"}
    ]
}
```

Solutions which I tried are as follow

```
levels = dict()
for n in test:
    levels.setdefault(n['parent_section_id'], []).append(n)
```

but this is not giving the output I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at this and came up with the following code. I am absolutely certain that this could be done better: I don't recommend using this for large volumes of data. If another, more experienced programmer could weigh in on this solution, I'd be grateful.

```
test = [
    {"id": "101", "logical_section": "ORGANIZATION", "parent_section_id": None},
    {"id": "102", "logical_section": "ORG_NAMES", "parent_section_id": "101"},
    {"id": "103", "logical_section": "ORG_ADDRESSES", "parent_section_id": "101"},
    {"id": "104", "logical_section": "SOURCEADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"},
    {"id": "105", "logical_section": "STANDARDIZEDADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"},
    {"id": "106", "logical_section": "ORG_EMPLOYES", "parent_section_id": "101"}
]

ans_dict = test[0]


def insert(tree, node):
    if node["parent_section_id"] == tree["id"]:
        if "child" not in tree:
            tree["child"] = [node]
        else:
            tree["child"].append(node)
    elif "child" in tree:
        for c in tree["child"]:
            insert(c, node)


for record in test:
    insert(ans_dict, record)


print(ans_dict)
```

This code uses a recursive binary tree approach. What makes it so inefficient is the fact that EVERY SINGLE NODE has the `insert()` function ran with the given node as a parameter, EVERY SINGLE TIME that a new node is inserted.

Comment: Thank you.. this works perfectly as I wanted and I am definitely gonna read more details on recursive binary tree approach and yes I am using for smaller dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses the Breadth First Search algorithm to construct a tree. Note that since dictionaries are mutable, all elements inside the input list will be modified. You would need to select the one/s where "parent_section_id" is None to find all of the parents.

```py
test = [
        {"id": "101", "logical_section": "ORGANIZATION", "parent_section_id": None},
        {"id": "102", "logical_section": "ORG_NAMES", "parent_section_id": "101"},
        {"id": "103", "logical_section": "ORG_ADDRESSES", "parent_section_id": "101"},
        {"id": "104", "logical_section": "SOURCEADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"},
        {"id": "105", "logical_section": "STANDARDIZEDADDRESS", "parent_section_id": "103"},
        {"id": "106", "logical_section": "ORG_EMPLOYES", "parent_section_id": "101"}
]

# No assumption about the position of the parent
nodes = [i for i in test if i["parent_section_id"] is None]
# Single parent
parent_idx = test.index(nodes[0])
# If more than 1 parent, then uncomment
#parent_idxs = [test.index(node) for node in nodes]

# Find all children
parent_id_vals = set([d["parent_section_id"] for d in test if d["parent_section_id"] is not None])

while nodes:
    focus_node = nodes[0]
    
    if focus_node["id"] in parent_id_vals:
        focus_node["child"] = []
    
    # Uncomment else clause if "test" is too large
    #else:
    #    nodes.remove(focus_node)
    #    continue
    
    for i in test:
        if i["parent_section_id"] == focus_node["id"]:
            focus_node["child"].append(i)
            nodes.append(i)
    
    nodes.remove(focus_node)
            
# If single parent node
ans = test[parent_idx]
# If multiple parents, then uncomment
#ans = [test[idx] for idx in parent_idxs]

print(ans)
```

I did this as a mini challenge. DCoxshall's answer is suitable for your needs anyway.